# Python exe cannot identify image file

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I'm making a Tkinter application and created an executable of my project containing the main.py file and 2 other helper .py files located in "path/to/python/project/folder" using Pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module PyQt5 --onefile -p "path/to/python/project/folder" main.py
```

At some point in the main.py file an image is selected by the user from their system and then shown in the GUI. To do so I create image.jpg in "path/to/python/project/folder". When running my code in an IDE things work fine but when I run main.exe I get the following error: `OSError: cannot identify image file 'image.jpg'`

There's also an empty image created in the same folder as where the .exe file is located.

Is there a way to make the .exe file behave like the original python 'project'? Or can one simply not create new files and access them from an .exe file?

EDIT: the user selects a video and the application shows the middel frame as an image that’s why a new image is created.

EDIT: here's some code to maybe clarify some things:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os


fpsGlobal = -1

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("TITLE")
        self.readyForAnalysis = False
        self.workdir = os.getcwd()
        self.data = None
        self.fps = fpsGlobal
        self.finished = False

        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.frame)
        self.file_expand = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.file_expand.add_command(label='Open...',command=self.openVideo)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_expand)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)


    def openVideo(self):
        '''Opens the video when open... button is clicked and shows a screenshot of a frame from the video'''
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/', title = 'Select file', filetypes = (("avi files",".avi"),("all files","*.*")))

        # if a video is loaded and openfiledialog is not cancelled
        if self.filename:
            # read videofile
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.filename)
            self.totalFrames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            global fpsGlobal 
            fpsGlobal = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, int(self.totalFrames/2))
            ret,frame = cap.read()
            cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame)

            # show image
            image = Image.open("image.jpg")
            #print("image.size   = (%d, %d)" % image.size)
            resizedImg = image.resize((704, 576), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedImg)
            self.label = tk.Label(self.frame,image=picture)
            self.label.image = picture
            self.label.pack()

            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            try: 
                os.remove("image.jpg")
            except: print("no")

            self.readyForAnalysis = True
            self.analyzeButton.configure(background='green2')
            self.welcome.config(text="Start the analysis of the video by clicking the 'Analyze' button." )


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1000x750')
    my_gui = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

So in the GUI the user is able to select a video file which later will be analyzed. To provide some feedback to the user i'll show the middle frame of the video as an image within the GUI. When running the code in my IDE everything works but running it from the .exe file I get an error (see error above) at line `image = Image.open("image.jpg")`

Comment: I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve but can you add a minimal working version of your code to question?

Comment: I added some code with additional explanation hope this helps you understanding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have found the solution to my own question. It is not possible to create files in an executable the same way as in a Python project folder and access them afterwards since there's no folder structure in the .exe file.

The way this probably can be solved is by using the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) library.